# AngularJS approach for communication between components?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My AngularJS web application has a view containing a grid with a toolbar for filtering data, above. It looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, there is a toolbar above the grid. Note that both of these controls inherit from a parent $scope, as they live inside the same parent controller. Though, each of these controls is a different directive (userFilterBar and userList).

When I type in the "Find" input box, I'd like to apply filtering against the records in the grid below. I'm trying to decide whether to facilitate communication between these components a) simply via the shared scope or b) via some form of event aggregation.

Is there a typical AngularJS approach for this situation, and what does it look like?

Comment: Why not use the scope when it's so readily available to you? What do you expect to gain/lose using events?

Comment: I want to avoid coupling different controls/directives.

Answer (score 1):

You should use ngFilter. This is what I used when I made something similar. It uses ngModel for the communication between components. Here is a good simple tutorial:

http://www.thinkster.io/angularjs/ET1iee6rnm/angularjs-ngfilter